# How to use Resource Controller to show different pages

Tags: php, laravel

I am curious - is it possible to use Resource Controllers everywhere, for instance, like a controller that displays different pages depending on some parameter in URL?

For example, I have two Resource Controllers :

```
PagesController
PostsController
```

Relevant routes :

```
Route::resource('', 'PagesController');
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
```

When I call for `php artisan routes`, all routes for `posts` seem obvious, for example, if I want to `show` specific post, then I can use next URLs for this :

```
/public/posts/1
/public/posts/2
/public/posts/3
```

These URLs will redirect request to this method :

```
class PostsController extends \BaseController {

    public function show($id)
    {
        print 'Show : ' . $id;
    }
}
```

**Question :** how to call the same method for pages if it does not have name and, given my routes, what URL should I use to call `PagesController@show`?

```
/public/1
/public/show/1
/public/1/show
```

I thought, that I can use URLs above, but they do not work and I get `HttpNotFoundException`

Comment: Change your route for your pages controller to `Route::any( '(.*)', function( $page ){
   //
});`